# Why the shape of the output from cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) changed?

Tags: python, opencv

I try the code below:

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
import io

.....

buf = io.BytesIO(ret.content)
image = Image.open(buf)
# result is (25,150,3)
print(np.asarray(image).shape)
img = cv2.cvtColor(np.asarray(image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# result is (25,150)
print(np.asarray(gray).shape)
```

The first print result is (25,150,3) and the second one is (25,150).

But I try the code below

```
imagePixel = cv2.imread(path, 1)
print(np.asarray(imagePixel).shape)
_, X_test = cv2.threshold(imagePixel, 96, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
print(np.asarray(X_test).shape)
```

The two output is (25,150,3)

I want to get the image shape (25,150,3), but I don't know how to fix the first code fragment.
I don't know why the shape of the output from cv2.cvtColor changed?
Thanks

Comment: Third value in "shape" is the number of colour channels. BGR/RGB/HSV etc have 3 channels. Grayscale has only one channel, so the value is stored directly (instead of a one-value array). You can "convert" gray to BGR/RGB to get 3 channels.

Comment: Adding to @h4z3 's comment, if you don't care about the number of channels but need the shape to be three dimensional then a simple `numpy.reshape(img, (25, 150, 1))` should do the trick

Comment: convert gray image back to RGB image and you will have gray image with 3 channels.

Comment: `X_test = cv2.cvtColor(X_test, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)`